# Generating inputs in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, input, components

I am trying to generate inputs on a button click and the amount of inputs is generated by a random number. Here is what I have so far, but it isn't working. I am very confused and feel like it should be working. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Image } from './Image.js'
import { Button } from './Button.js'
import { images } from './assets/images.js'
import { Countdown } from './Countdown.js'
import { DisplayCount } from './DisplayCount.js'
import { Inputs } from './Inputs.js'

class Game extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.timer = null


    this.state = {
      currentImg: 0,
      timer: null,
      ranNum: null
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

countdownClock = async (newRanNum) => {
const startingNum = newRanNum * 20;
for(let i = startingNum; i >= 0; i--) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({
           timer: i
         })
        resolve()
     }, 1000)
   });
  }
}

generateInputs = (newRanNum) => {
    const inputs = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= newRanNum; i++){
      inputs.push(
        <Inputs type='text'   className='textInputs' />
      )
    }
    return inputs;
  }

  handleClick(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    let newRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    this.countdownClock(newRanNum)
    this.generateInputs(newRanNum)
    let current = this.state.currentImg;
    let next = ++current % images.length;
    this.setState({
      currentImg: next,
      ranNum: newRanNum
    })
  }

  render(){
    let src = this.state.currentImg;
    return(
      <div>
        <Countdown name={'Countdown: '} countdown={this.state.timer} />
        <DisplayCount name='Word Count: ' count={this.state.ranNum} />
        <Image src={images[src]} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <div>
          <ul>
          {this.generateInputs()}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Inputs component:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Inputs = (props) => {
    return (
      <li className={props.className}>
        <input value={props.value}  />
      </li>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is your `generateInputs()` function takes a parameter for number of inputs you wanted to render `but you are not passing any parameter` to `this.generateInputs()`

The second thing is you are returning an array from this function but not mapping your array in the render function, So do in this way.

```
this.generateInputs(10) // pass parameter here


this.generateInputs(10).map((item, index)=>item)
```

In this Snack, I have done the same thing but with react-native

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/smiling-carrot

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here...

`generateInputs = (newRanNum) ...`

and here...

`{this.generateInputs()}`

You're input rendering function is expecting a parameter it's not getting, and since that returns as `undefined` the loop never runs. :)

In general, it is most common to separate *state* (eg, number of inputs) from the rendering, and only have the rendering *respond* to state.  Perhaps you had originally intended `generateInputs()` to produce the array, and not render them (?)

Comment: The function would render I believe, since you are returning the array.  I think @Waheed Akhtar might be mistaken about that.

Comment: I attached a working demo with it, Please have a look at it, `He is returning an array but not mapping that array`, Here is I have done this https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/smiling-carrot

Comment: Respectfully, arrays of components are one of the acceptible types from a render function in React.  There is absolutely no difference between 

```
export default (props) => {
  
  const elements = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    elements.push(<h6>{`Element ${1}`}</h6>)
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {elements}
    </div>
  )
}
```
and 
```export default (props) => {
  
  const elements = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    elements.push(<h6>{`Element ${1}`}</h6>)
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {elements.map((e)=>e}
    </div>
  )
}```

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me properly edit after 5 minutes I guess...

In React, arrays of components are perfectly acceptable as long as they are surrounded by an enclosing component.  We often see components return their own `{children}` array without mapping.  If you try your own example without the map, you'll see it works just fine.  The issue was that he was not passing a param into function which was resulting in the loop not being executed.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely educational. It was that I was not passing the param into the function. I thought that it did it through my ```handleClick``` function. It works now. I appreciate it so much.

Comment: @ArtemisPrime param for number of items is necessary but mapping is not necessary.